# Why does my "Hello World" Tkinter program only open a blank, black screen?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am teaching myself python, but am running into problems with Tkinter.  I created a simple program based on some videos I've been using to learn as I go.  From all my research thus far, I cannot find a problem in the code, it is only four lines show below.  The code creates a window called "tk" that is completely black with no text inside that is the correct size for what the text should take up if it were to be there.

I have tried to select the text inside the window to see if there is anything there, but there isn't.  I've tried to change the background color to white using the bg command, but nothing changes with the window.  I have opened "empty" windows using only the first and last line, which again creates a window of the correct size from everything I've seen online, but again is completely blank and black instead of white or gray as it should be.

I am using PyCharm (PyCharm 2021.3.1 (Community Edition)) as my compiler on a MacBook Pro. (iOS is on 12.0.1).  Tkinter is on (Tcl 8.5 & Tk 8.5 (8.5.9)).

When I click run, everything seems to run smoothly with no errors.  Honestly, I'm at a complete loss as to what the problem is.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

myLabel = Label(root, text="Hello World! Why can't you see me?")

myLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

# root.configure(bg='white')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I run your code on Python 3.10 on 64-bit Windows 10, I see a window with that text. I also start the script from PyCharm, but since that's an editor, it has no bearing on the problem - your OS, installed version of Python and perhaps "other software" are more relevant here. I'd add macos or something of the sort to the tags, since it's apparently relevant to your problem. I'd remove pycharm, because it likely isn't (you can easily check by running the script outside pycharm with `python myscript.py`)

Comment: *Cant reproduce* under `Python 3.7.2 and tkinter 8.6` with `Windows 10`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this due to running python 2.7.

When we updated to python 3.10 the issue disappeared.

Try checking your version of python.